# How can I make my Rails app return a 500 status for assets that do not compile due to an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'd like to be able to write a test to ensure one of my SCSS assets can compile successfully, but it's difficult to do reliably do that by matching the body of the response. I'd like to simply be able to check the response code when accessing the asset's URL, but it seems my app is returning a successful 200 status code even for assets that compile with errors. Observe:

```
$ curl -i http://domain/assets/my_asset.css

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1153
```

However, my logs clearly state that the asset does not compile OK:

```
Error compiling asset my_asset.css:
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$var".
Served asset /my_asset.css - 500 Internal Server Error
```

And the asset body does contain the error message, so I know it's serving up a "bad" asset, but the status code does not reflect that.

Is there any way I can make my app return a 500 in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Curl is used to transfer data from or to server. In case there exist previous versions of the same file it just gets the data.

In case you want to know the status of the new version of the asset then add unique identity for the created asset or you have to remove the previous one before you create a new compilation (and make sure cache is expired in the server for the same asset).

Hope this helps.

Regards,
HBK

Comment: Please do provide the reason for downvote. so I could get something out of it! Thanks, HBK